# Delete section of streamreader

Tags: c#

I end up with all the deliveries in the following array

```
public static ArrayList myDeliveries = new ArrayList();
```

It is loaded into the listview. I select an item as follows:

```
iDeliverySelected = lstDeliveryDetails.SelectedItems[0].Index;
```

I am struggling to understand how I can select an item and use a delete button to remove it from the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to save a set of objects to disk, then read them back (and do that repeatedly as the objects change), I would say you need to look into [serialization and deserialization](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3110371/SerializationDeserialization-in-NET.htm).

This is essentially what you are doing already manually, but there are ways to automate this and make it easier.

You can use the [`XMLSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class to do this, but you will have to mark your `Delivery` objects with the [`SerializableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) if they are not yet marked as such.

**Edit**: (following comments and update to question)

If, before calling `saveFile()`, you remove the selected item from the ArrayList, it will get saved without that item:

```
myDeliveries.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
//Or
myDeliveries.Remove(selectedObject);
```

Comment: @ Oded - I have edited the question to show a saveFile method.
I am wondering if I literally need to identify the selectedindex and remove it from the array?

Comment: @Luke - If you want to keep your code as is, you will indeed need to remove the selected item from the ArrayList.

Comment: What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Someone might have a smarter solution, but I think you're going to have to generate the entire text file after the user has made changes via the GUI.

Comment: At the moment, I can edit a file. It saves and loads the file seamlessly.
I assume to delete something I would remove it from my arraylist?

Comment: You could use the Remove function from the arraylist. I'd be happier using RemoveAt, because you can pinpoint exactly which row is being deleted, but you'd have to make sure you can map from your ListView item to the ArrayList index somehow. (One trick is to tag each ListView item with the ArrayList index; on the other hand, you can use a cleverer control like a ComboBox that supports DisplayMember/ValueMember).

Answer (score 1):

That's how you remove the selected item:

```
lstDeliveryDetails.Items.RemoveAt(iDeliverySelected);
```

Comment: This only removes it from the listview, not the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown how you populate the myDeliveries or lstDeliveryDetails, so I will make some assumptions. When you delete an item from lstDeliveryDetails, you also need to delete the same item from myDeliveries, using the Remove method. When you have finished making the changes to the list, you persist it to file using a StreamWriter:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("../../MealDeliveries.txt"))  
{  
    foreach (object obj in myDeliveries)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(((Delivery)obj).DeliveryName);
        // etc
    }  
}
```

If you use a List collection instead of ArrayList, you do not need to cast to (Delivery) either, you can just do "foreach (Delivery delivery in myDeliveries)".

Comment: If I want to remove the iSelectedDelivery from the myDeliveries, myDeliveries[iSelectedDelivery] should work? How does remove work on this? And then I will use my save function to save it.